# How to hover content, exclude some div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code, when hover
[image: bug]

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#content").mouseenter(function(e) {
      if ($(e.currentTarget).children().hasClass(".nav")) {
            console.log("Outside");
        } else {
            console.log("Inside");
        }
   }).mouseleave(function(e) {
      console.log("Outside");
   });
});
```

Error when I hover .nav, result is Inside

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put `.` in the `.hasClass()`:

```
.hasClass("nav")
```

---

Or you could try to change the selector as a collection selector like `$('div')` instead:

```js
$("div").mouseenter(function(e) {
  if ($(e.currentTarget).is(".nav")) {
    console.log("Outside", e.currentTarget);
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else {
    console.log("Inside", e.currentTarget);
  }
}).mouseleave(function(e) {
  console.log("Outside");
});
```

```css
#content{width:200px; height:200px; margin:30px auto; border:solid 2px red;}
.nav{width:50px; height:20px; float:right; margin:160px 0 0 0 ; border:solid 2px green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content">
<div class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is target what we are trying to hover and focus on it. As you see in the code the selector goes and get li within ul and then you can do your action.

I used hover which is short hand for .mouseenter and .mouseleave. I hope it will help you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.nav li').hover(
    function(e) {
      console.log('inside');
    },
    function(e) {
      console.log('outside');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
ul{
border: 2px solid gray;
}
ul li{
padding: 5px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 15px;
border: 1px solid black;
margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
</ul>
```